# List items are replaced with new reference when adding in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, cursor

Based on the query i am getting some **features** in **pFeatureCursor**. I am adding that **features** into a **List(IFeature)**. When iam iterating the **pFeatureCursor** and adding the values into **pFeatureList** all values in the list are replacing with the new reference **pFeature**

Please  refer my code below

```
//List is declared globally
List<IFeature> pFeatureList = new List<IFeature>();

//In a method i am trying to add features in a list
//based on queryfilter
pFeatureCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pQueryFilter, true);
IFeature pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature();
while (pFeature != null)
{
  pFeatureList.Add(pFeature);
  //lstQuerValue is the listbox
  lstQueryValue.Items.Add(pFeature.get_Value(1).ToString());

  //When below line is execute whatever the recent pFeature 
  //value is replacing all the items and duplicating in pFeatureList
  pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature();
 }
```

Please give some idea how to avoid it.

Comment: duplicated or replaced with a new reference?

Comment: yes replaced with a new reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what's happening is that all the items in PFeatureList are the same, then try using a non-recycling cursor.

```
pFeatureCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pQueryFilter, false);
```

Comment: Thank you problem solved but what actually happening when i replaced **true** with **false** plz..

Comment: This determines what type of cursor your search method is returning. Read the API reference for IFeatureClass.Search and also look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000047000000 under the section Understanding Recycling